# Cron job using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to have cron job in asp.net application. Here is what I want to implement:

"If there are 50 new users then send me newsletters according to their needs"

I have done this by creating a console application running on server but I am looking if there is a way like cron jobs?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe an SSIS package that runs on the database end if you are using sql server.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the windows task scheduler that would take a command similar to a cron job.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It works in a very similar way to cron.  You add tasks that execute at intervals that you define.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Quartz.net, it can easily handle cron triggers

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html  <-- Very useful for gettng started

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of cron-jobs in windows is either task scheduler, or a windows service.

In my opinion, you can go with a windows service that polls the db, and sends the newsletter.

If you already built the console app, extract the relevant code in a BusinessLogic Class, and 
create a new Windows Service project.
See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWindowsService-9f2f568e
I'm guessing you already have a working SMTP server to which you can connect from the server,right?

see also answers to  [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12021013/1446608)

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I have a question; what is solution if hosting is shared? We can not install Windows Service?

Comment: In a shared hosting environment i think Windows Services are out(but you might want to check this with your host).This leaves scheduled task and exotic simulations. See this [StackOverflow thread]http://stackoverflow.com/q/5245612/1446608) some creative ideas, one from Jeff Atwood, probably used on SO: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/ . Not the ideal setup, but hey, you need to work with what you have.